# Why does the conditional formatting in this question only apply to a single row?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I want to colour row "4" using this custom function "=REGEXMATCH(B4;"Skorpion")" in conditional formatting, but that doesn't work. Only "A4" is blue, and I wanted all row 4 in blue colour.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a row highlight use:

```
=REGEXMATCH($B4; "Skorpion")
```